# How to get True for X^2>= 0?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic

How to get true when introducing the expression $x^2 \geq 0$ in mathematica ?
how do I specify that x is real ?

```
GreaterEqual[x^2, 0, Element[x, Reals]]
```

Comment: `Simplify[x^2 >= 0, Element[x, Reals]]`  or `Refine[ x^2 >= 0, Element[x, Reals]]`?

Comment: also  `Assuming[ Element[x, Reals], Simplify[ x^2 >= 0]]` and `Assuming[ Element[x, Reals], Refine[ x^2 >= 0]]`

Comment: Post the Mathematica code is better than the LaTeX code.

Comment: `Resolve[ForAll[x,x^2>=0],Reals]` produces `True`.

Comment: Thanks, @kglr please put the comment in a response so that I can validate it as a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Simplify[x^2 >= 0, Element[x, Reals]]

Refine[ x^2 >= 0, Element[x, Reals]]

Assuming[ Element[x, Reals], Simplify[ x^2 >= 0]]

Assuming[ Element[x, Reals], Refine[ x^2 >= 0]]
```

all give `True`.